# Damp spot on covered front porch after rain

Tags: water-damage, porch

There is a damp spot on my covered, elevated-front porch that is on a stone foundation every time it rains. Gutters are doing their job and draining away from foundation and I have placed several dishes out to see if there is a leak from above but there is nothing. The boards look to be decently spaced so I don’t think condensation is an issue. Thoughts?[image: front porch]

Comment: Instead of dishes you might need to be out there when it rains.  The water stain on the third board from the right might be from water running down the wall.

Comment: @crip659, yes and the 3 boards in a row with the ends totally damp also point to it coming from the wall.

Comment: @crip659 Does that point to a siding issue then? Our roof was just redone less than a year ago so I don’t think that’s the issue

Comment: Probably not a siding issue, maybe a sealing issue between the roof/patio cover and wall or something else.  Finding where the water/dampness is coming from is the first job.  It might just be rain blowing in, you only say the patio is covered, but don't mention if it is closed in(walls).

Comment: @crip659 I’m out here with 3 pans laid out and a bunch of paper towels stuffed under the siding wall to test that theory. I’ll report back. And the patio isn’t enclosed so rain blowing in is a possibility, it’s just strange that the front of the porch is dry while the back of the boards get damp

Comment: What is beneath the porch?